# How to create and use services in angular-boilerplate (AngularJS + RequireJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

In use [angular-boilerplate](https://github.com/galkinrost/angular-boilerplate) project I can't figure it out how to create new service and call inside controllers.
I've declared service app/services/**first.js** like this:

```
define(function (require) {
require("services/_module");

var angular = require("angular");
angular.module("App.services").service("AppFirstService", function ($scope) {

    return {
        sayHello: function() {
            return "Hello, World!"
        }
    };
});
});
```

add its requirement to **_package.js** file:

```
define(function (require) {
require("services/_module");
require("services/first");
});
```

and finally injected it to controller app/controllers/**first.js**:

> define(function (require) {
>       require("controllers/_module");
>       require("services/first");

```
var angular = require("angular");

angular.module("App.controllers").controller("AppFirstCtrl", ['$scope', 'AppFirstService', function ($scope) {

}]);
});
```

but got the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- AppFirstService
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use $scope as service dependency:

```
angular.module("App.services").service("AppFirstService", function ($scope) {
```

$scope for controllers only.